# Program for finding factorial of a number. Correct but result is printing more than once

Tags: java, numbers, factorial

**I am new to Java.** I made this program which finds out factorial of a number. The result is coming correct but it is printing several times. e.g. if we enter a number 4 as input. "Factorial of 4 is 24" is printing 5 times on console. Please clear the flow of this program. As the recursive method "factor" is used before printing the final result, Why it is coming more than once on console?

```
public class Fact {
    int number;
int LocalNumber;

void m(){
    Scanner obj= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number");
    number=obj.nextInt();
    LocalNumber=number;
    }

int product=1;
void Factor(){
    if(number>=1){
    product=(product*number);
    number=number-1;
    Factor();
    }
    System.out.println("Factorial of"+" "+LocalNumber+" "+"is"+" "+product);
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    Fact object=new Fact();
    object.m();
    object.Factor();

}
}
```

Comment: You are calling `Factor()` within itself. Since the sysout at the end of that method is unconditional, it will happen each time the method is called. Also, please adhere to java naming conventions: variable and method names should start with a lower case letter.

Answer (score 0):

your function is recursively called. so print the result only when number==1, that means last iteration is reached

```
if(number==1)
  System.out.println("Factorial of"+" "+LocalNumber+" "+"is"+" "+product);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place the `System.out.println()` statement inside `else {}`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fact {

    int number;
    int LocalNumber;

    void m() {
        Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        number = obj.nextInt();
        LocalNumber = number;
    }

    int product = 1;

    void Factor() {
        if (number >= 1) {
            product = (product * number);
            number = number - 1;
            Factor();
        } else {          //THIS IS NEEDED
            System.out.println("Factorial of" + " " + LocalNumber + " " + "is" + " " + product);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Fact object = new Fact();
        object.m();
        object.Factor();

    }
}
```